# PHP, PDO ODBC, MSSQL, Linux Data source name not found (РЕШЕН)

Tags: php, linux, sql-server, pdo, unix-odbc

disclaimer: Перечитал весь гугл, перепробовал все, что можно.

/etc/freetds.conf

```
 [sm-dbr]
         host = sm-dbr.mydomain
         port = 1433
         tds version = 7.0
         client charset=CP1251
         Handle Type = 1
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini   (и то и другое пробывал)

```
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
 Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
 Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2260.0
 Threading=1
 UsageCount=2

[FreeTDS]
 Description=FreeTDS Driver
 Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
 Setup=/usr/lib64/unixODBC/libtdsS.so
 UsageCount=1
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[sm9ss]
Driver=FreeTDS
ServerName=SM-DBR
Database=sm9ss
TDS_Version=7.0

[Default]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

pdo.php

```
<?php
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
$dbh = new PDO ("odbc:sm9ss","user",'pass');
```

> Array ( [0] => informix [1] => odbc [2] => sqlite [3] => sqlite2 )
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified in
>   /srv/www/htdocs/api/pdo.php on line 6

PHP 5.3.17 (cli)

```
# php -i | grep -i pdo
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_informix.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_odbc.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => informix, odbc, sqlite, sqlite2
pdo_informix
pdo_informix support => enabled
PDO_ODBC
PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перечитал свой вопрос и увидел, куда еще можно применить научный тык. Может кому пригодится.

В моем случае(SLES 12, PHP 5.3), datasource надо указывать не в /etc/odbc.ini, а в /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini

Чтоб им не икалось.